# Installing SL4A Python for Android

Tags: android, python, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo, sl4a

I am totally new to Android and was looking to try out Android with python.

I downloaded the Android SDK from this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html for MacOSx 10.6.7. After downloading, installing and adding the Android 2.2 platform using the offline 2.2 platform installer, I needed to download to these two additional SL4A files for configuring Andriod scripting.

These two files namely `sl4a_r2.apk` and `python_for_android_r1.apk` had to downloaded and installed by pointing the emulator's browser to this link [code.google.com/p/android-scripting/](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

However for some reason, I am not able to run the internet on my mac for some reason due to driver issues and I have to download these on my other windows pc.
The usual method I have come across is to download these two files from the emulator's browser and then run them from the download history.
But how can I install these files from the emulator after I have these package on my mac, since I cannot run the internet from the emulator due to the reason stated above.

Comment: Seems like you should be fixing your Mac, rather than anything else. It's very odd that you should think there would be "driver issues" preventing your Mac from connecting to the Internet. What is this, 1995?

Answer (score 2):

You have downloaded the two apk's and transfered them to your mac and now need to install them in the emulator also running on your mac?

To do this use ADB from the android SDK:

```
adb install /filepath/on/your/mac/to/xx.apk
```

I hope I have understood your question correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest the same as suggested by Troll.

But make sure `adb` path has been included in the system path. Otherwise adb command will not work from other directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered in the other question how to install Py4A completely off-line: 
[How to install interpreter for SL4A in offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850640/how-to-install-interpreter-for-sl4a-in-offline/)

Unfortunately it requires a small source change, and therefore you need to build your own Py4A from the sources.